# IntelliJ IDEA - Sync between Eclipse .classpath and IntelliJ .iml

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea, classpath, project

Say I open an Eclipse project in IntelliJ IDEA, and then I add a library dependency in Eclipse.
How can I sync the .iml file with the modified .classpath one? If there is a way...

Comment: You can't unless you reimport the module/project or write a plugin.

Comment: @Meo I could also write a little batch script

Comment: You can [export From IntelliJ IDEA to Eclipse](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/exporting-an-intellij-idea-project-to-eclipse.html#d231816e7) as a one time operation, but there is no auto-synchronization.

Comment: @Andrey isn't that the opposite? That's for creating .classpath from .iml and I need the opposite.

Comment: Yes it is) I just in case wanted you to know about similar functionality in IntelliJ IDEA.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep dependency consistency across IDE's and achieve even more if you want it... You must use Maven.

Maven is awesome about it. You only will have your project's real code and a file called pom.xml.

You are able to add dependencies in the Maven way to that pom.xml and no matter what you are able to run your project in IntelliJ, Netbeans, and Eclipse without a problem, even across multiple developer on different IDEs.

You can learn a good deal about Maven from this tutorial:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/maven/

It shows you it's usage in Eclipse, IntelliJ and Netbeans in the last chapters of the tutorial.